# OWSTIMER.Exe issue: The following error occured while trying to read the ConnectionString property

Tags: 2013, timer-jobs, logging, uls, timer-service

I'm investigating an issue on a Timer Job.

In the ULS log file I noticed below error message which is thrown by OWSTIMER.Exe.

*"The following error occured while trying to read the ConnectionString property. Object reference not set to an instance of an object."*

And idea about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If its your custom timer job & if you are using the on-premises version of SharePoint 2013 than please debug the code first as this can be an error of the code.

You can debug the timer job by attaching the same OWSTIMER.Exe from the visual studio.

Comment: In addition to this, perhaps a misplaced WFE join and detach may leave the configuration database in an inconsistent state.In such situations , the timer do complain about the same connectionString issue in the ULS

Comment: No, it's a built in timer jobs which manages alerts in SharePoint.

Comment: it simply means you have configuration error in SharePoint